# bounded left skewed distribution giving a specific mean and SD R

Tags: r, distribution, envstats

I am looking for help to create a left-skewed distribution giving a specific mean and standard deviation. EnvStats package has a function to creates bounded right-skewed distribution as shown below with mean=2, sd=.9, lb=1,ub=5, but not left-skewed.

```
library(EnvStats)
set.seed(20)
# Rigth skewed
x <- rlnormTruncAlt(100, 2, .9, 1, 5)
hist(x)
mean(x)
skewness(x)
```

Comment: Beta distribution is bounded and can become skewed in either direction depending on the parameters.

Comment: Why not use EnvStats with the mean adjusted to the complementary location in the range, then just flip the distribution end-for-end?

Comment: @pjs I am not sure how to do it! any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: If your bounded range is [0, 5] and you want a mean of 4, generate a right-skewed distribution on [0, 5] with a mean of 1.  You want the complementary mean to be as far from the midpoint (2.5) as the target mean.  Then transform every X to (5-X), which flips the distribution right-to-left.  More generally, if the range is not bounded by zero you can subtract the midrange from each value, flip its sign, and then add the midrange back to flip a distribution.